# Mozilla Firefox Extension

Tags: javascript, firefox-extension

Внезапно стало нужно расширение, которое бы по нажатию перемещало пользователя от div'а к div'а. Начал гуглить, наткнулся на пример:

index.js

```
var buttons = require('sdk/ui/button/action');
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");

var button = buttons.ActionButton({
  id: "mozilla-link",
  label: "Visit Mozilla",
  icon: {
    "16": "./icon-16.png",
    "32": "./icon-32.png",
    "64": "./icon-64.png"
  },
  onClick: handleClick
});

var data = require("sdk/self").data;

function handleClick(state) {
     tabs.open("http://google.ru");
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "title": "Title",
  "name": "Name",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Add-on",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "Author",
  "engines": {
    "firefox": ">=38.0a1"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "keywords": [
    "jetpack"
  ]
}
```

По нажатию на иконку открывается сайт. Пытаюсь поменять, чтобы по нажатию кнопки было хотя бы alert(1). Но ошибка - alert is not defined
Пытался подключить jQuery, тоже ничего не вышло. Как все это сделать? Может я чего-то не понимаю? Что за принцип работы расширений то? Думал, быстренько напишу на javascript и готово. А тут ничего не работает у меня..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала почитайте https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/Add-ons/SDK

По поводу же вопросов:

> Пытаюсь поменять, чтобы по нажатию кнопки было хотя бы alert(1). Но ошибка - alert is not defined

Использовать alert в данном js файле не имеет смысла, поэтому он там и не определён.

> Пытался подключить jQuery, тоже ничего не вышло.

Аналогично со случаем выше. Данный js файл не работает напрямую со страницами, поэтому jQuery там тоже ни к чему.

> Что за принцип работы расширений то?

Алгоритм действий в таком случае будет состоять из двух шагов:

1. По нажатию на кнопку открываете необходимую страницу.
2. После того, как она загрузится подключаете **скрипты содержимого**, в котором будет рабочий код (alert, jQuery и т.п) для работы с данной страницей.

Пример кода:

```
function handleClick (state) {
  tabs.open(
    url: "url.com",
    onReady: function (tab) {
      tab.attach(
        contentScriptFile: './js/content-script.js'
      );
    }
  );
}
```

В content-script.js: `alert("Привет мир");`

Comment: Благодарю Вас!!!

Comment: А как, собственно, привязать к клику по расширению выполнение функции из файла content-script.js?

Comment: @Gikas опишите подробнее, что Вы подразумеваете под "выполнением функций по клику"?

Comment: Ну, изначально по клику по расширению открывалась страница сайта, а мне нужно, чтобы по клику срабатывала функция из скрипта, который я подключил к activeTab как contentScriptFile

Comment: Обнаружил такую вещь: `port.emit("alert", "Message from the add-on");`. Надеюсь правильно я делаю